# Metasploit pattern not working for buffer overflow for SLMail 5.5

Tags: exploit, buffer-overflow, metasploit

I'm trying to do a buffer overflow on SLMail 5.5. I see where EIP is when I send 2606 A's to the program using my script. However, I cannot get the Metasploit pattern creator to work. I want to use this as it helps find the offset. When I use the produced characters in my script, SLMail acts like nothing happened. I do see it took my connection and username, but the password won't break the program using the generated pattern, but using the archaic A flood does.

Is there some kind of trick to this? I'm at a lost as to why random, unique strings won't work but thousands of A's will.

Comment: Welcome to InfoSec, unfortunately there's no good way to answer this question.  We don't know what system you're trying to exploit, or what the end result is supposed to be.  We also can't tell you exactly what SLMail 5.5 is doing once your payload is delievered. You might try Metasploit's Unleashed if it's [Metasploit specific](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/).  If it's possible to debug the SLMail daemon I'd suggest that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I found the issue was actually I was not pasting in the correct pattern string into the script. It seems silly, but my clipboard management program was not using my most recent copy+paste selection like I thought. After selecting the pattern on the clipboard manager, I was able to get this working.Thanks!